# MySQL FullText Hyphens and Braces return error (ORIGINALLY: PDO prepared statement not doing its job?)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel, full-text-search

**I've updated this question as a perplexing new twist to the problem has shown up.**

MySQL is not handling hyphens or braces correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(firstname, lastname, about) AGAINST('-' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

returns

```
syntax error, unexpected $end
```

[image]

The same thing happens if I enter a `(` or `)`. I know it's only those because entering anything else such as `test` works just fine

*I'm on MySQL 5.7.4M*

**---UPDATE---** 
This error disappears if  I switch from InnoDB to MyISAM. Is this a bug with the relatively new FULLTEXT support in InnoDB?

***------OLD Question----***
I'm implementing a "search users" feature in my application built off of Laravel and PHP, and I'm making use of the `fulltext search` in MySQL. Laravel not having a function for this, I used a basic `DB::select()` to get the job done. The problem is that while it is using a prepared statement, it's acting like it isn't (kinda).

**My Code:**

```
return DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(firstname,lastname,about) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($query));
```

**FYI for those who want to know, this is the `DB::select()` function**

```
public function select($query, $bindings = array())
    {
        return $this->run($query, $bindings, function($me, $query, $bindings)
        {
            if ($me->pretending()) return array();

            // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
            // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
            // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
            $statement = $me->getReadPdo()->prepare($query);

            $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

            return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());
        });
    }
```

However, if I put in something like: `--` (to emulate a comment in a mysql injection), I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, unexpected '-'
```

I know it's only stuff like this, as putting in `Test` or `Hello World` works perfectly fine.

Comment: the error message is hardly googleable. Is it complete? Can't you try the same query in console, adding $query content to the query directly?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I've updated the question with a query to the console

Comment: at least there are wrong quotes on the screenshot

Comment: @YourCommonSense those same wrong quotes execute successfully with `test` or any other input. It's just windows font rendering

Comment: Then use *stable* build

Comment: @YourCommonSense tried, same thing on stable 5.6

Comment: the error nessages you are getting are highly unusual. especially from a screen... Heck. It's april fools question

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wish. Perhaps the error will disappear magically tomorrow. But the fact being that it's not working on 5.7 on my local machine nor 5.6 stable on my server, I doubt it's april fools :P.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've updated my question slightly, only appears on InnoDB. Switch to MyISAM and it works

Comment: I've just run into the same error Kevin, on MariaDB 10.3.11.  Disappears if I remove `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.  Did you find any useful information on this error?  I can work around it, but it's odd that it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Expected behaviour it seems.  My fix: `$term = str_replace(['~', '"', '<', '>', '@', '-', '+', '*', '(', ')'], '', $term);`

(I then add a plus sign in front of every word as that's the behaviour I want)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not you, then it's someone else is joking on you.
But mysql error that looks like exactly as PHP syntax error is quite evident

Comment: It's not a PHP error, it IS a MySQL error: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Why does it have a dollar sign in it?  No idea, but it definitely comes from MySQL, not PHP.  Command line mysql returns it, for example.